# Which size for background image in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to create a View in Android with this background:

[image]

In the header should be two TextViews and a icon and the content can be different. My problem now is that I don't know the size of a TextView (or some other view) on the users device. So in which size should I store the picture so it is displayed correct on all devices? Of course I do not want to waste storrage for this picture in my app so I should be the smalest size.

Or is it posible to create something like this (particularly the shadow between header and content - which are only 2 lines of black and white with a transparency of 12%) in a shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 9patch image for this. Details can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) but basically you'll only need a 2x1 pixel image. Then you can use the tool described in the link to generate a 9patch file which you use as your image file. Android then intelligently stretches the image for you depending on the width of the screen.

**Alright, an edit:**

I decided to help you a bit more. You're right about the NinePatch tool, it looks like it needs to be at least 2x4 large. I quickly made up a small image in Gimp

[image]

I then imported it into the NinePatch tool and set the appropriate not stretchable parts

[image]

Then I imported it into my drawable-nodpi folder and referenced it in an ImageView. Make sure you use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFC2C2C2" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Header" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient_line_image" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

which gives me

[image]

Just incase you want it, here's my 9patch file

[image]

I'm not sure at all what you mean by "both TextViews are in the header" though...

Comment: Okay thanks for that but if I want to open a 2x1 pixel image in the 9 patch programm it fails to open it. With larger images it is no problem. Any ideas why? And how can I be shure that both TextViews are in the header?